# Can I add a "Counter" within a FOR loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a little batch file (see below) that does what the REM statement says.

When executed it displays each filename in turn as it's being processed (with a progress bar (of sorts) as the file is 're-written' to disk) but I would also like it to display a "counter" (starting at 1) that increments with each file processed so that when the final file is processed the counter will then display the **total** number of files that have ***been*** processed.

Is there any ***simple*** change I could make to achieve this?  (I am not a coder, the batch file was given to me by someone else with whom I have lost contact.)

```
REM --ooOO  This adds c.365ms silence to all mp4 video files in the folder (adding 364 bytes to file size)  OOoo--

for %%a in (*.mp4) do mp4box "%%a" -add 0.2sSilenceM.mp3
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a counter is quite easy:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=0
for %%a in (*.mp4) do (
  set /a counter+=1
  echo processing file !counter!: %%a
  mp4box "%%a" -add 0.2sSilenceM.mp3
)
echo total processed files: %counter%
```

You need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) to use the counter inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much , Stephan.  That worked a treat! 
Thank you too for the referral to more details about "delayed expansion"
(although most of that was **_way_** over my head. )

Comment: @Highlander please read, [What to do when someone answers my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) explains the details (warning - your head may explode by reading it). But for now - accept that (unlike any other language) variables are replaced by their values *when the parser reads the (logical) line* (even before executing anything), while delayed expansion happens *during execution*.